# Determining zeros and poles from an equation

Tags: signal

I'm given an equation \$y(n) = a_0 {x(n)} + a_1 {x(n-1)} + a_2{x(n-2)}\$ which is used to design a simple filter to remove a narrowband disturbance with frequency \$F_0\$ = 70 Hz. I'm told to let the sampling frequency Fs = 280Hz.

Using the above information how could I go about determining the zero's and poles? The notes I have aren't the greatest in clarity so any explanations/links to resources that might be helpful in understanding what's going on would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for taking your time to read this!

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: First step - get a z-transfer function from your difference equation.

Comment: @LeonHeller Funny how people assume such things. It's not a homework question, it's a past exam question I'm trying to understand.. if you read my question correctly not once did I ask you to purely give me a solution (I was looking for explanations/resources that explain how I can go about answering this question).

Comment: @Chu Thanks for your reply. Would I use the fact that: Y(z) = A(z)/B(z) where A(z) = a0 + a1*z^-1 + ... + aN*z^-N and B(z) = 1 - b1*z^-1 - ... - bN*z^-n? I know that the poles and zero's are found by solving for the denom and num set to zero. Thanks!

Comment: If I follow the aforementioned idea I get: H(z) = (a0*z^2 + a1*z + a2) / (z^2)-> we have one pole at z = 0 and the zero's would be found from solving the numerator using the quadratic formula?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You have to then find suitable locations for the complex conjugate zeroes and relate these to the 'a' coefficients. This is where the unit circle becomes important - I guess you know how frequency relates to the unit circle locus

Comment: ... there's a double pole at z=0 btw, but it doesn't make any difference to the gain calculation at various frequencies.

Comment: ok so after reading a bunch of stuff i think ive got somewhere- so using the frequency stuff given and using exponentials i believe the complex conjugate zero's will be found via z1 = e^+-0.5pi (since at this angle, the zeros will be on the unit circle) so we get: 0 + i and 0 - i. this in turn means that a0*z^2 + a1*z + a2 =0 when z = 0+i and 0-i-> a0*z^2 + a1*z + a2 = (z-i)(z+i) = z^2 +1 if we compare co-efficients a0 = 1, a1 = 0 and a2 = 1. Does this look correct? Thanks again

Comment: @Chu (forgot to notify you)

Comment: See answer, might need tidying up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit circle locus is z=e^jwT, where w=rad/sec, T=sampling increment, and the angle, A, of the rotating vector which describes the circle is A=wT radians. e.g. for w=0, A=0 rad; for w=pi/(2T), A=pi/2 rad, etc.

The gain of a z-TF, which is more important than phase angle in this filter design problem, is given by: (product of vector lengths from the frequency of interest on the unit circle to each zero)/(product of vector lengths from the frequency of interest on the unit circle to each pole).

For example, a system: G(z)=(z-0.5)/z will have a pole at z=0 and a zero at z=0.5. This system will provide gains of: 0.5/1.0 at wT=0; 1.118/1.0 at wT=pi/2; and 1.5/1.0 at wT=pi

For your filter, T=1/280 and the frequency of interest is 70Hz=140.pi (rad/sec), so wT=pi/2. So let's say we want a filter with a small gain at 70Hz. How about placing a zero close to the circle at pi/2, say at z=j0.98 (and we must also have the conjugate at z=-j0.98) and a pair of poles at z=0? That will give us a gain of; (0.02)(1.98)/1.0 = 0.04 at 70Hz, and at wT=0 the gain will be approximately 2.0. As the locus proceeds from 0 to pi the gain reduces to a minimum at pi/2. As we continue around the circle we get aliasing, and mirroring of the frequency response.

With this design we might propose a z-TF: G(z)=(z-j0.98)(z+j0.98)/z^2, where we need the 2nd order denominator to avoid a physically unrealisable TF.

For complete rejection of 70Hz, we might propose: G(z)=(z-j)(z+j)/z^2 = (z^2 +1)/z^2; with a difference equation: y(n) = x(n) + x(n-2), but this has a DC gain of 2, hence might decide to implement y(n) = 0.5x(n) +0.5x(n-2) to achieve unity DC gain.

Incidentally, placing a zero (and conjugate, of course) in the neighbourhood of a known interfering signal, e.g. 50Hz or 60Hz mains noise, is often appropriate. Additionally, this is one time when aliasing is our friend, as odd and even harmonics of the noise signal are also eliminated!

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write out this explanation, I thoroughly appreciate it (the notes I have been given don't go into a tenth of how much you've been able to help me with lol).I have a final question if you have time to help: I need to determine the co-efficients a0, a1, and a2 but its subject to a constraint whereby y(n) = 1 and x(n) = 1 for all n. I've plugged in these values into the original equation that was given at the start of the question but I'm at a dead end, so I'm guessing this isn't the route to follow. Any pointers? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: OK, if y(n)=x(n)=1 for ALL n (i.e. from -inf), then the final DE in the answer does the job. But note that the z-TF is not defined for n<0 (TF's assume zero initial conditions), so if you obtain a unit step response from the TF, using: Y(z) = G(z)z/(z-1) you will get y(n)=0.5 for n=0, 1 and y(n)=1 thereafter. Practically, that would mean that the filter works as intended, except for the the first two sampling instants after switching it on.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, could you explain more about what would be used to identify the co-efficients? I haven't seen any real mention of DC/Unity in my notes sorry. I understand how you got y(n) = x(n)+x(n-2) but didn't understand where the 0.5 co-efficients came from. Thanks again! @Chu

Comment: For a Laplace TF, the steady-state gain (or DC gain) is determined by letting s=0 (from s -> jw, and w=0 is 'DC'). For a z-TF, the SS gain is found by letting z=1 (since z -> e^sT -> e^jwT -> e^0 = 1 for w=0). Hence G(z)=(z^2 + 1)/z^2 will have a DC gain of 2 and the SS response to a unit step will be 2. To make the SS gain = 1, divide the TF by 2: G(z)=(z^2 + 1)/2z^2

Comment: Ok, so a0 = 0.5, a1=0 and a2=0.5 right? Thanks for taking your time out to help! @Chu

Comment: Yes that's correct.